# How will you determine if the issue with VPN is on remote site or local site?

Tags: vpn

[image]

If a remote host connected to a server via VPN is not able to ping the server, how'd you determine if the issue is with VPN at "server side" or VPN at "client side"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture packets on the TUN interface - what goes in comes out on the other side. If a packet does enter the tunnel but doesn't reach the destination, the far side is the problem.

To analyze *all* possible problems you likely need to capture on both sides.